# SQLSTATE=55023 Error on Specific DB2 Region

Tags: delphi, db2

I'm getting the below error when I try to execute the Query in DB2 database through Delphi 10 code, this is happening only for one Region...
The same code is working fine for the other Regions..

Could not open query/table[FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0471N  Invocation of routine "SYSIBM.SQLPRIMARYKEYS" failed due to reason "00E7900C".  SQLSTATE=55023

The old code which have been complied in the Delphi 5 is working for all regions.. any help?

Comment: Is [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21452742) any help? I have [many Google results](https://www.google.nl/search?q=Invocation+of+routine+SQLPRIMARYKEYS+failed+due+to+reason+"00E7900C"), although none for `SQLPRIMARYKEYS` specifically.

Comment: Thanks Jan Doggen, Most of the Google results are for WML and Im not sure about that part guess I need to study on that part, one thing I didn't Understand is this region alone is not working for the Migrated code (Recently I have migrated the code from Delphi 5 to Delphi 10 Seattle), the same region is working with Delphi 5 code. Strange :-|

Comment: Several questions:
1) Which data access library (name and version) you was using in Delphi 5 ? 2) Delphi 10 is Delphi DX10 ? 3) What do you mean "Region" ?